# Please, help me with this query - mysql

Tags: mysql

Please, help me with this query:

Table conversation_reply:

```
#id     reply           from_id     to_id       timestamp
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1       Hello           1           2           2017/05/23 12:26:40
2       Hi              2           1           2017/05/23 12:26:42
3       Hello           3           2           2017/05/22 01:26:40
4       What R U Doin?  1           2           2017/05/25 09:48:40
```

Table users:

```
#id     name        ipAddress
--------------------------------
1       Tin         78.78.78.78
2       Leo         78.78.78.77
3       Max         78.78.78.76
```

Table conversation:

```
#id     from_id     to_id       timestamp
---------------------------------------------------
1       1           2           2017/05/23 12:26:40
2       2           1           2017/05/23 12:26:42
3       3           2           2017/05/22 01:26:40
4       1           2           2017/05/25 09:48:40
```

How can I achieve query to get results that look like this:

```
#id     name        reply
-----------------------------------
1       Tin         Hello
2       Leo         Hi
3       Tin         What R U Doin?
```

I'm lost

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are looking to get conversation between two users displayed in order of how the conversation/chat proceeds.

Also assuming that you will be using this query in an application where the two users chatting are known to the application (i.e. logged in to the system). In this case I will assume that these users are users.id 1 and 2.

Note that table `conversation` is not required to get the desired results.

Now for the query:

```
SELECT cr.id,
u.name,
cr.reply
FROM
users u INNER JOIN conversation_reply cr ON cr.from_id=u.id
WHERE cr.from_id in (1,2)
ORDER BY cr.`timestamp` ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

First I don't see the use of conversation table.

Second,what I understood is that you only want those records where conversation started. for example  3 ping to 2 saying "Hello" but 2 didn't reply back
So this record won't be included.

```
create table #conversation_reply(id int,reply varchar(50),from_id int
,to_id int,timestamps datetime)
insert into #conversation_reply VALUES
(1,'Hello',1, 2 ,'2017/05/23 12:26:40')
,(2,'Hi',2, 1 ,'2017/05/23 12:26:42')
,(3,'Hello',3, 2 ,'2017/05/22 01:26:40')
,(4,'What R U Doin?',1, 2 ,'2017/05/25 09:48:40')
--select * from #conversation_reply

create table #users(id int,name varchar(50),ipAddress varchar(50))
insert into #users VALUES
(1,'Tin','78.78.78.78')
,(2,'Leo','78.78.78.77')
,(3,'Max','78.78.78.76')


create table #conversation(id int,from_id int,to_id int
,timestamps datetime)
insert into #conversation VALUES
(1, 1, 2,'2017/05/23 12:26:40')
,(2, 2, 1,'2017/05/23 12:26:42')
,(3, 3, 2,'2017/05/22 01:26:40')
,(4, 1, 2,'2017/05/25 09:48:40') 

select from_id,name, reply
from
(
select distinct cr.*
from #conversation_reply cr
inner join #conversation_reply cr1
on cr.from_id=cr1.to_id and cr.to_id=cr1.from_id
)t4
inner join #users u
on t4.from_id=u.id



drop table #conversation
drop table #conversation_reply
drop table #users
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
Crep.[#id],
u.name, 
crep.reply

FROM 
conversation_reply Crep join users u on Crep.[from_id] = u.[#id]
order by Crep.[#id]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output id column filled with sequential numbers, you could do the following:

```
set @row = 0 ;

select
  @row := @row + 1 as id
, U.name
, R.reply
from users U
  join conversation_reply R on(U.id = R.from_id)
where U.name in ('Tin', 'Leo')
order by R.id;
```

Example session:

```
mysql> set @row = 0 ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select
    ->   @row := @row + 1 as id
    -> , U.name
    -> , R.reply
    -> from users U
    ->   join conversation_reply R on(U.id = R.from_id)
    -> where U.name in ('Tin', 'Leo')
    -> order by R.id;
+------+------+---------------------+
| id   | name | reply               |
+------+------+---------------------+
|    1 | Tin  | Hello               |
|    2 | Leo  | Hi                  |
|    3 | Tin  | What are you doing? |
+------+------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions are helpful - but I modified the query for myself.
If I want to query messages between 1 and 3 - then it should be blank because there is no conversation.

I used conversation table

```
SELECT id FROM conversation WHERE (from_id=1 AND to_id=2) OR (from_id=2 AND to_id=1)"
```

Then I queried in php:

```
SELECT name, reply, timestamp FROM conversation_reply JOIN user ON user.id=conversation_reply.from_id WHERE conversation_reply.id= $key ";
```

I don't really know if this is a good method, so I will test it